# when click on the one column tooltip shown on the other column in amcharts on mobile

Tags: reactjs, amcharts4

When clicking one cloumn on amchart bar chart the tooltip is not showing on small screen like mobile but on desktop it is showing correct.
Can any one please help me why on mobile screen tooltip not showing properly when click on the single column?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUzcC.png)

Comment: can you please add working demo so we can take better look?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUzcC.png
Here I have attached one image. 
Here The tooltip showing on the Austrilia coulmn which is ok but i am getting this tooltip when clicking next to right column.